# What does the phrase 발음이 새다 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

발음이 새다

On the TV show Produce 48 Soyu from Sistar said this to one of the girls after she sang the song. I don't understand what it means exactly since she was saying the words when she was singing... what is it about her pronunciation/singing exactly? if it's easier to explain in Korean, use Korean.

https://clyp.it/5nbn1ng4

Comment: Just to be clear, are they saying "발음이 세다" (the pronunciation is **strong**) or "발음이 샌다" (the pronunciation is **leaky**)?  If you heard something like "발음이 새네요", it's more likely the latter.

Comment: it is definitely the latter it's from a tv show

Comment: if it was the former I wouldn't even be asking. sseda is a very common word and I can think of multiple songs with that word in the title ie sseun unnie by Jessie.

Comment: Thank you for the additional reference, but could you double-check because there's no way a native Korean speaker would say "발음이 **새다**".  새다 is a verb, so it must be "발음이 **샌다**".  (Also, you don't have to write the same sentence twelve times.)

Comment: Although 소유 said "발음 되게 많이 새는 거 알아요?" and some people use 발음 with 새다, I believe that **바람** should be used with 새다 (e.g., 그 사람은 말을 할 때 잇새로 바람이 샌다). The phonic similarity between 발음 and 바람 can confuse people.

Answer (score 2):

**새다 leak**

Gas is leaking from the pipe.

파이프에서 가스가 새고 있다.

I had my wisdom tooth pulled out today, so I can't pronounce words
properly now

내가 사랑니를 빼서 발음이 새는거 같아요.

Comment: Something like the beaver in  https://youtu.be/vNDFy3zoBGE ?

Comment: Yes. beaver. 1) Especially, this frequently appears in boxer. Maybe Sylvester
Stallone. 2) Correctness is related with bone, but leaking is related with
tongue, lip, and muscle around mouth. So it can appear temporarily after orthodontics, or in person of
Palsy.

Comment: here is the audio https://clyp.it/5nbn1ng4